# Capabilities and pricing of Amazon's cloud computing platform?

Tags: asp.net, sql, cloud-computing, ajax

I'm finding it very hard to estimate how much my web application might cost running in Amazon's cloud? My app is similar to stackoverflow.com - asp.net, ajaz, sql database. Can anyone estimate how much it might cost to run stackoverflow in Amazon's cloud?

Comment: you haven't mentioned anything specific regarding bandwidth, cpu usage, disk usage, RAM requirements, etc, so i'm not sure how you expect we could give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you assessed your VM, storage and bandwidth requirements? Figure that out on paper, and then enter the estimated values into the [AWS Simple Monthly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html) for an approximate run-rate.